# Finding the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/p},\zeta_{2n})$

Tags: galois-theory

How to find the Galois group of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/p},\zeta_{2n})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$? Here $n$ is a positive integer, and $p$ is an odd prime factor of $n$.

Comment: Did you show that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n})/\mathbb{Q}) = \{ \zeta_{2n}^b \mapsto \zeta_{2n}^{ab}, a \in \mathbb{Z}/2n\mathbb{Z}^\times\}$ ? Then assume $p\nmid \varphi(2n)$, what can you say of $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/p}):\mathbb{Q}] ,[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n},2^{1/p}):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n})],[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n},2^{1/p}):\mathbb{Q}] $ ? So what is $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n},2^{1/p})/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n}))$ and $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n},2^{1/p})/\mathbb{Q})$ ?

Comment: @reuns: Why is $p\nmid\varphi(2n)$?

Comment: $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/p}):\mathbb{Q}] = ?$ then use the multiplicativity of degree of extension to find $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n},2^{1/p}):\mathbb{Q}]$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n},2^{1/p}):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n})]$